# Groupby into list for non consecutive values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to group by this dataset

```
    col1    col2
0   A   1
1   B   1
2   C   1
3   D   3
4   E   3
5   F   2
6   G   2
7   H   1
8   I   1
9   j   2
10  K   2
```

into this

```
1 : [A, B, C]
3: [D, E]
2: [ F; G]
1: [ H, I]
2: [ J,K]
```

so it has to capture the difference in appearances of the elements and not group all at once.

So far I was able to do the normal groupby, `df.groupby("col2")["col1"].apply(list)` but it isn't correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need distinguish consecutive values by compare shifted values foe not equal with cumulative sum, last remove second level of `MultiIndex`:

```
s = (df.groupby(["col2", df["col2"].ne(df["col2"].shift()).cumsum()])["col1"]
       .agg(list)
       .reset_index(level=1, drop=True))
```

Comment: Any performance difference between `agg` and `apply`?

Comment: @SayandipDutta - Not easy question, I guess `agg` should be faster, because `apply` is more general.

Comment: @SayandipDutta - Here should be better use `agg` for general solution if want change `["col1"]` to `["col1", "col3", 'colN']`

Comment: @jezrael is there a way to keep the ordering similar to the one in the original data?

Comment: @ombk Yes, use `.groupby(["col2", df["col2"].ne(df["col2"].shift()).cumsum()], sort=False)["col1"]` instead `.groupby(["col2", df["col2"].ne(df["col2"].shift()).cumsum()])["col1"]`

Comment: @jezrael: I jsut wanted to ask you if it's done only by using python `itertools groupby `will it be faster/efficient than using pandas functionality ?

Comment: @Pygirl - It should be faster, if large data maybe pandas wins, maybe the best test in real data

Answer (score 1):

Since Jezrael already answered is using pandas. I would like to add non pandas method.

I know this is not an efficient method but for learning purpose I included.

Using `itertools's groupby`

```
from itertools import groupby
last_index = 0
for v, g in groupby(enumerate(df.col2), lambda k: k[1]):
    l = [*g]
    print(df.iloc[last_index]['col2'],':', df.iloc[last_index:l[-1][0]+1]['col1'].values)
    last_index += len(l)
```

---

```
1 : ['A' 'B' 'C']
3 : ['D' 'E']
2 : ['F' 'G']
1 : ['H' 'I']
2 : ['j' 'K']
```

Comment: It will maintain the order of their occurence.